# how to fix UNAUTHENTICATED error while trying to create an asset report using PLAID? Plaid createAssetReport using cloud function

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, plaid

I'm trying to create an **asset report** from Plaid, I'm using Cloud Functions for these calls, all the other cloud functions work (link, transactions, balance) but `assetReportCreate` fails and return UNAUTHENTICATED

￼[image]

The Plaid logs do not show the call...so I guess something is wrong in my Cloud Function, but the Google Console Logs show status 200.
[image]

has anybody experienced the same issue and know how to fix it?

PS: just double checked today to make sure I'm authenticated and I am...
[image]

```
//create ASSET report
exports.createAssetReport = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const accessToken = data.accessToken;
  const daysRequested = data.daysRequested;
  // const options = {
  //   client_report_id: '123',
  //   webhook: "https://www.example.com", //to let you know when report is ready, get link from cloud console
  // };

  const configuration = new Configuration({
    basePath: PlaidEnvironments[functions.config().app.env],
    baseOptions: {
      headers: {
        "PLAID-CLIENT-ID": functions.config().plaid.client_id,
        "PLAID-SECRET": functions.config().plaid.secret,
      },
    },
  });

  const plaidClient = new PlaidApi(configuration);

  //call the createLinkToken  METHOD of the plaidClient instance!
  return plaidClient
    .assetReportCreate({
      access_tokens: [accessToken],
      days_requested: daysRequested,
      //options,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const assetReportId = response.data.asset_report_id;
      const assetReportToken = response.data.asset_report_token;
      return assetReportToken; //token is needed to retrieve the report via //pdf/get
    }) 
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "internal",
        " Unable to create asset report: " + err
      );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that for whatever reason the function wasn't open for **all users to invoke**, adding a principal with role: "cloud functions invoker" fixed the issue, shame on you google cloud, I spent two full days on this!! jk, thanks for your services but fix these small details and you could become the #1 cloud provider

[image]